# Start child activity from listview Button click in android

Tags: android

I am working with an android application. In that, first I need store all the data from webservice and later querying data from db and updating in listview.

My listview item contains checkbox and button. When I clicked the button or check box, it is working (showing LOG) fine but I need to start child activity when I click the button in the listview.

This is my Adapter class,

```
public class GuestListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String > arrayListFirstValue;
    ArrayList<String > arrayListSecondValue;
    ArrayList<String > arrayListThirdValue;
    public GuestListAdapter(Context mcontext, ArrayList<String> arrListFV,ArrayList<String> arrListSV,ArrayList<String> arrListGuestTV)
    {
        arrayListFirstValue =arrListFV;
        arrayListSecondValue =arrLisSV;
        arrayListThirdValue =arrListTV;
        context = mcontext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayListFirstValue.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayListFirstValue.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guest_list_item, parent, false);
            }



         TextView txtFirstValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_firstname);
            txtFirstValue .setText(arrayListFirstValue.get(position));
         TextView txtSecondValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_lastname);
         txtSecondValue .setText(arrayListSecondValue.get(position));
         TextView txtThirdValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_guest_count);
         txtThirdValue .setText(arrayListThirdValue.get(position));
         Button btnInfo = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_info);

         CheckBox checkBoxCheckins = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxIsCheckedIn);


         btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 System.out.println("Adap button **********");

            }
        });
         checkBoxCheckins.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                 System.out.println("Adap checked **********");

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

Finally my question is I need to start child activity when I click the button in listview.
Please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you have juste to start a new activity using the activity s context passed to adapter like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just change your current listener to this:

**Edit:** Because you don't tell that listview in child activity of a tab at first.

```
    btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewTabActivity.class);// Your tab parent activity.
intent.putExtra(Constants.TAB_INDEX, tab index number) // pass the index of the tab you want to move to.

    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

In your tab activity (parent activity), you create a variable to store index of your desire tab

```
private int tabindex = 0;
```

Check this in `onCreate`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            setContentView(R.layout.main_tab_screen);
            tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            tabWidget = getTabWidget();


            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                tabindex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Constants.TAB_INDEX,
                        0); // you check if this parent started from other activity. You child activity will pass the desire tab index here. If nothing is special, just display the  1st tab.
                            }
            initTab();
        } 
    }



    protected void initTab() {
        Intent intent;
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        // Add tab child
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Inbox").setIndicator(
                getTabIndicatorView(MainTabActivity.this, "Hộp thư",
                        R.drawable.tin_nhan_tab_selector));
        intent = new Intent(this, com.vtcmobile.ui.InboxActivity.class);
        // intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_IS_LOAD, isload);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
....

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabindex); // use the tab index to get the right tab you want.
        tabHost.getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(tabindex);

    }
```

Comment: The program works and print the log but the problem is I not able to start child activity, remember one thing, I am in custom adapter class (Base adapter) with out extends activity, I unable to start activity or start child activity is not working. Is there any way to start child activity with in custom adapter class or any solution for my problem.

Comment: I saw your adapter contructor had context. You just pass that context in `onClick`.

Comment: First thank you for your reply, But I like to tell you one thing here that is I am displaying the list view in tab bar. When I clicked the button in list item it need to take me to the another activity with in tab bar. So I need to Start Child Activity. Not a normal intent. please guide me.

Comment: @Dhamodharan You should add that importance information to question. Without that everyone think your issue is simple. I update my answer. You can ask more at Android People [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people)